# Why doesn't my number guessing game output anything to the console?

Tags: java, loops

My program doesn't output anything to the console. I'm not sure what I did wrong. I'm required to use `System.in.read()` and can't use a `Scanner`. I'm also required to use any loop of my choice.

```
package MyGuessingGame;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
*
* @author Anthony
*/
public class MyGuessingGame {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int guess = 0;
        int answer = 8;
        //Todo change to random
        boolean correct = false;

        while (correct == false); {
            System.out.println("Please enter your guess!");
            guess = System.in.read();
            System.in.read();
            if (guess == answer) {
                correct = true;
                System.out.println("Congradulations You have won!"); 
            } else if (guess != answer) {
                correct = false;
                System.out.println("Sorry try again."); 
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
while(correct == false);
```

needs to lose the semicolon at the end. As it stands now, it's an infinite empty loop and your program won't proceed past that statement.

Comment: Not to worry, everybody has done that at some point. The ones who say they haven't just haven't done it *yet*.

Comment: Either that or they are filthy liars.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Greg's answer, `System.in.read()` returns a `char`. If you store it in an `int` you will have the ASCII representation of the value.

For example 56 is the ASCII for '8'. The offset of the numbers in the ASCII table in HEX is 0x30. So, for the code to actually work, you should subtract 0x30 to the received value.

So, you should change the input line to the following one:

```
guess = System.in.read() - 0x30;
```

Comment: Thanks I needed that as well.

Comment: No, not ASCII. Java uses Unicode/UTF-16. `char` holds one UTF-16 code-unit, one or two of which encode a codepoint, one base codepoint and zero or more combining codepoints form a semantic/visual unit called a grapheme (which you can call a character). For example, "\u0061\u0301" form the grapheme á and "\uD834\uDD60" forms . There's a bit to learn about Unicode but once you do, you can use the Java `String`, `Character` and `char` accurately.

Answer (score 0):

First, when you have a `boolean` type, there is no need for you to check `(correct == false)`, you can simply use the operator `!` like this `(!correct)`

The problem that you have is that you are using the semicolon after the while, while loop has no semicolon. So you have this `while(!correct);`, so it stays on an infinite loop without executing the inner block of code

```
    int guess = 0;
    int answer = 8;
    //Todo change to random
    boolean correct = false;

    while(!correct)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter your guess!");
        guess = System.in.read();
        if (guess == answer) {
            correct = true;
            System.out.println("Congradulations You have won!");
        }  else {
            System.out.println("Sorry try again."); 
        }
    }
```